# Trying to use datatables in Slim 3 what is the best way/structure to make the ajax call

Tags: datatables, slim

I am trying to use datatables inside a view in Slim 3. To me the simplest way to use datatables is to make an ajax call, because I don't know how I would pass a json object to datatables from a controller. I'm not sure where to put my ajax calls. Should I create another folder in my App folder and call it ajax? Or am I going about this datatables all wrong?

here is my controller

```
<?php


namespace App\Controllers\Dashboards;

use App\Controllers\Controller;

class AdminDashboardController extends Controller
{
    public function listAction($request, $response)
    {
        return $this->view->render($response,'dashboards/admin.html.twig');
    }
}
```

here is my view

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block body %}
    <h1>this will be the admin dash</h1>

{% endblock %}

{% block javascripts %}
    {{parent()}}
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $.ajax({
                url: "../src/App/ajax/getAll.php",
                type: "GET",
                dataType: 'json',
            }).done(function (result) {
                console.log(result);
            }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, error) {
                console.log("getArchivedPo: " + error);
            });
        });
        </script>
{% endblock %}
```

and here is my ajax

```
<?php

$conn = $container['db'];
//$conn = $container->get('db');

$admin = array();

if ($conn) {
    $sql = "SELECT trannum, 
                   trantype, 
                   tranbatch, 
                   trandate, 
                   username, 
                   trvnum, 
                   tranaccount, 
                   tranamt, 
                   transtatus, 
                   trannumdocs 
            FROM   BD.BDPTV 
                   INNER JOIN BD.BDUSERS 
                           ON BD.BDUSERS.usernumber = BD.BDPTV.tranuser 
            WHERE  transtatus NOT IN ( 3, 7, 5 )";

    $stmt = db2_prepare($conn, $sql);

    if ($stmt) {
        $result = db2_execute($stmt);
        if ($result) {
            while ($row = db2_fetch_array($stmt)) {
                $admin[] = array(
                    'trnum' => $row[0],
                    'trtyp' => $row[1],
                    'trbatch' => $row[2],
                    'trdate' => $row[3],
                    'usrnam' => $row[4],
                    'trvnum' => $row[5],
                    'tracct' => $row[6],
                    'tramt' => $row[7],
                    'trvsts' => $row[8],
                    'numdoc' => $row[9]
                );
            }
        } else {
            error_log(db2_stmt_errormsg($stmt));
        }
    } else {
        error_log(db2_stmt_errormsg($stmt));
    }
} else {
    error_log(db2_conn_errormsg());
}

$admin['data'] = $admin;
echo json_encode($admin);
```

Also, righ tnow I'm getting this error `<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined variable: container in <b>/www/slim/htdocs/bd/src/App/ajax/getAll.php</b> on line <b>3</b><br />
{"data":[]}`

So should I put my ajax somewhere else?

my routes

```
<?php

$app->get('/', 'HomeController:indexAction')->setName('home');
$app->get('/admindash', 'AdminDashboardController:listAction')->setName('admindash');
$app->get('/ajaxrequest', [AdminDashboardController::class, 'ajax'])->setName('myAjaxRequest');
$app->get('/poentry', 'PoController:entryAction')->setName('poentry');
$app->get('/poedit', 'PoController:editAction')->setName('poedit');
$app->get('/poarchive', 'PoController:archiveAction')->setName('poarchive');
$app->get('/voucherwithpo', 'VoucherController:entryWithPoAction')->setName('voucherwithpo');
$app->get('/voucherwithoutpo', 'VoucherController:entryWithOutPoAction')->setName('voucherwithoutpo');
$app->get('/edituser', 'UserController:editAction')->setName('edituser');
$app->get('/adduser', 'UserController:addAction')->setName('adduser');
$app->get('/poarchivedash', 'ArchivePoDashboardController:listAction')->setName('poarchivedash');
$app->get('/voucherarchivedash', 'ArchiveVoucherDashboardController:listAction')->setName('voucherarchivedash');
$app->get('/notedash', 'NoteDashboardController:listAction')->setName('notedash');
```

Comment: Could you add the code how you are doing this right now?

Comment: I am not successfully doing it right now and every attempt I have made I have erased the code and tried to start over.

Comment: Just show that, then I can understand what you trying to archive, I'm not 100% sure right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly about the error message you get: You need to include parts of the slim start up where you define the container and the `$container['db']` otherwise that cannot be found.

But now the solution where you do not have an additional php file:

You should add a route for the ajax request you could do that in the `AdminDashboardController` as well

```
class AdminDashboardController {
    // listAction function

    function ajax($request, $response) {
        // copy from your ajax file 
        return $response->withJson($admin);
    }
}
```

then add a route:

```
$app->get('/ajaxrequest', 'AdminDashboardController:ajax')->setName('myAjaxRequest');
```

And then you can reference that route inside your twig file

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "{{ path_for('myAjaxRequest') }}",
        type: "GET",
        dataType: 'json',
    }).done(function (result) {
        console.log(result);
    }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, error) {
        console.log("getArchivedPo: " + error);
    });
});
```

Comment: I get this error ```"message": "Callable AdminDashboardController::class does not exist",``` I'll paste my routes above

Comment: You are a god send! Thank you for you're help you have no idea how much I appreciate it!